# MySQL Split string by character mutli-part

Tags: mysql

I want to add a temporal column to a query.

I have a table `example_ip_db`, that contains `s1,s2,s3,s4,e1,e2,e3,e4,cc` rows.

These `s1,s2,s3...` rows means `start of ip range`, and `end of ip range` for the `e1,e2,e3...`. In case that for example the ip range where `1.1.1.1` to `2.2.2.2` for country China (`CN`), these will be the data:

- Starting rows `s1`,`s2`,`s3`,`s4` will equals `1`. (`s1.s2.s3.s4`/`1.1.1.1`)
- Ending rows `e1`,`e2`,`e3`,`e4` will equals `2`. (`e1.e2.e3.e4`/`2.2.2.2`)
- The `cc` row will equal `CN`.

What I want is to add a column `county` to a non existing `example_ip_db` table/row/data. Something like the generated column with the `count(*) as 'amount'` query.

How can I split the IP for this?

Comment: Please edit your post and format the table data into tabular form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use SUBSTRING() function in mysql.

For example.

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING('habonytest', -3);
      -> est
 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING('habonytest', -5, 2);
      -> yt
 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING('habonytest', FROM -5 FOR 4);
      -> ytes
```

Also mysql has SUBSTRING_INDEX() function.

example:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('myid@domain.com', '@', -1);
      -> domain.com
 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('myid@domain.com', '@', 1);
      -> myid
```

[See it more detail](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! (@Star_Man)

Solved:

```sql
SELECT IP, SUBSTRING_INDEX( IP, '.', 1 ) AS part1, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( IP, '.', 2 ) , '.' , -1 ) AS part2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( IP, '.' , -2 ) , '.', 1 ) AS part3, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( IP, '.' , -1 ) AS part4,
    (SELECT `cc`
    FROM `example_ip_db`
    WHERE `s1` <= part1
    AND `e1` >= part1
    AND `s2` <= part2
    AND `e2` >= part2
    AND `s3` <= part3
    AND `e3` >= part3
    AND `s4` <= part4
    AND `e4` >= part4
    ) AS CC
    FROM `example_saved_ip_from`
    WHERE 1
```